# What's meaning of " http://www.google.com/m?client=ms-{CID}&amp;source=android-home"?

Tags: android, browser

I found the android default home page is " `http://www.google.com/m?client=ms-{CID}&amp;source=android-home`", what's it meaning?
Why not "`http://www.google.com`"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that you are retrieving a page that is adapted for android by Google.

Comment: I want to know the meaning of "m?client=ms-{CID}&amp;source=android-home", what it presents?

Comment: Google may use this to track android requests and display the page adapted for android which is why 'source=android-home', don't know much about 'm?client=ms-{CID}', it may be used as an id for the google server side to perform functions maybe.